# Quartz.Net multiple User Stations

Tags: quartz.net

I'm using Quartz.Net for sending specific emails on specific date/time.
My application has many users.
I'm calling Quartz.Net procedures in program.cs which run at application start.
So, if my users starts the application does it look like it will send the emails multiple times for the same emails? Or will it send only once, no matter how many users starts the application?
Can anyone please explain?
This is my code (basically a sample from Quartz.NET just for testing).
This code is inside program.cs

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        try
            {
                common.logging.logmanager.adapter = new common.logging.simple.consoleoutloggerfactoryadapter { level = common.logging.loglevel.info };
                ischeduler scheduler = stdschedulerfactory.getdefaultscheduler();
                scheduler.start();
                ijobdetail job = jobbuilder.create<hellojob>()
                    .withidentity("job1", "group1")
                    .build();
                itrigger trigger = triggerbuilder.create()
                    .withidentity("trigger1", "group1")
                    .withschedule(cronschedulebuilder.dailyathourandminute(10, 00))
                    .forjob("job1", "group1")
                    .build();
                scheduler.schedulejob(job, trigger);
                thread.sleep(timespan.fromseconds(60));
                scheduler.shutdown();
            }
        catch (schedulerexception se)
            {
               console.writeline(se);
            }
    }
}
public class hellojob : ijob
{
    public void execute(ijobexecutioncontext context)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: All depends on where you're storing your jobs, and how you set them up. Edit your question with some code so we can see what you've tried.

Comment: You'll find you get better help if you post specific questions with specific code examples. You've basically asked "I've copied some code, which I haven't shown you. Will it work?"

Comment: Sorry for that, my comments were too long, so I answered below...

Comment: Also, check out the 2-minute tour http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: OK, passed code for original question.

Comment: Any ideas? Thoughts? Anything?